# Json implicit Reads: type mismatch?

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

I'm using Play 2.3.4, and I've defined a simple model class as:

```scala
case class User(
  @Id
   id: Int,
   name: String
) extends Model

object User {
  def find() = { /* some code here */}
  implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = User(
      (json \ "id").as[Int],
      (json \ "name").as[String]
    )

    def writes(user: User) = JsObject(Seq("id" -> id, "name" -> name))
  }
}
```

And that is quite straightforward. But I'm getting a compile error:

```
Error:(31, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 /Users/asheshambasta/code/finit/app/models/users/User.scala:31: type mismatch;
  found   : models.devices.User
  required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.users.User]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple problems with the code above. The compilation error you're receiving is because `reads(json: JsValue)` should return `JsResult` and *not* the model. This is because you need to account for failures when defining `Reads`. `id` and `name` also need to be `user.id` and `user.name` in `writes`. This will compile:

```
object User {

    implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {
        def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(User(
            (json \ "id").as[Int],
            (json \ "name").as[String]
        ))

        def writes(user: User) = Json.obj("id" -> user.id, "name" -> user.name)
    }
}
```

However, this will throw an exception if there is an error in the JSON, because `as[T]` is not safe.

```
scala> val testJs = Json.parse("""{"id":"2", "name": "test"}""")
testJs: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"2","name":"test"}

scala> testJs.validate[User]
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray())))))
```

Defining `Reads` this way for simple object is almost always not worth it, and can be much better accomplished by using JSON combinators.

```
object User {
    implicit val reads: Reads[User] = (
        (__ \ "id").read[Int] and 
        (__ \ "name").read[String]
    )

    implicit val writes: Writes[User] = (
        (__ \ "id").write[Int] and 
        (__ \ "name").write[String]
    )    
}
```

JSON combinators will not throw exceptions like the first snippet of code, and they will accumulate all of the errors into the `JsResult` when validating. In a simple case like this, JSON inception would be even better:

```
object User {
    implicit val format: Format[User] = Json.format[User]   
}
```

There are also `Json.reads[T]` and `Json.writes[T]` macros in case you need something custom for `Reads` but not `Writes` or the other way around.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. It solves my problem and also helps making things much clearer.